# Inspect ZIP file for contents

Tags: php, search, archive

User uploads ZIP file.

PHP searches ZIP file for "*.adi".

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$za = new ZipArchive();

$za->open($target_file); 

for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){ 
$stat = $za->statIndex( $i ); 
print_r( basename( $stat["name"] ) . PHP_EOL );
}
$ResultOfZipFileSearch = explode( $stat["name"],PHP_EOL );
if (array_search("*.adi",$ResultOfZipFileSearch)) {
echo "ADI file found in ZIP...";
} else {
    echo "No ADI file found in ZIP";
}
```

If ADI file ***IS*** found, script still echoes "No ADI file found in ZIP".

What's wrong please?

EDIT: Solved the problem.

```
 if ($zip->open($target_file) === true) {
 for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) { 
 $entry = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
 if(preg_match('#\.(adi)$#i', $entry)) {
     echo "ADI found";
 } else {
     echo "NO ADI found";
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe in this case `array_search()` is looking specifically for the string '*.adi' not anything '.adi' which I what I think you're actually after?

Comment: Jon, thank you. Yes, I'm looking for "anything".adi. I assumed the * was a wildcard.

Comment: So the simplest way of doing this is instead of using array_search, just loop around the results of the explode, and do a `strpos(...) !== false` to see if there's a match on each item (then break if you don't care after you've found one).

Comment: Please Jon or anyone, an example of how I would do this? My PHP knowledge is very basic, most of this is not my code, I have simply modified parts of it by Googling for what I want it to do, but now I've hit a brick wall.